# Can't run Kubectl and Helm commands in GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm, kong

I'm trying to automate the deployment of Kong in a Kubernetes cluster using a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. I have an agent connected to my cluster and in my pipeline script I'm able run kubectl commands within my cluster. The next step is to run Helm commands but when I do I get "helm: command not found". Is there an image I can use that allows for kubectl and helm commands? How will I be able to run those Helm commands inside my cluster? Is it possible to have multiple images in a script?

This is my pipeline script in GitLab:

```yaml
deploy-job:      
  stage: deploy  
  environment: production
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
  script:
    - echo "Deploying Kong application..."
    - kubectl config get-contexts
    - kubectl config use-context test-project/kong:kong-agent
    - kubectl get pods -n kong
    - helm version
    - echo "Kong successfully deployed."
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll run into your current problem a lot.  My recommendation here is to maintain a custom image that both `kubectl` and `helm` (and any other tooling you may need).  Also try to explicitly reference a specific tag/version rather than `latest` -- it goes a long way when you inevitably need to troubleshoot an error that you were "getting today but not yesterday".

Comment: Thanks Glen, I'm going with a Ubuntu image and then installing curl, kubectl, helm, etc. That is also good advice on the version!